Why does GtkText's context menu (copy, paste) stop working; If css border is applied on GtkText?
I want to apply a border to GtkText Widget using css but facing issue. If I apply the border via CSS, the copy paste option in the default right click context menu stops working. Showing this warning --  Gtk-WARNING **: 23:17:00.572: Broken accounting of active state for widget 0x5591d99d8220(GtkPopoverMenu) .
How to apply outer border on GtkText widget without any issue?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static const char *css =
  "text {"
  "        all: unset;"
  "        border: 1px solid black;" /*copy past from right click contextmenu not working by this line */
  "        min-height:20px;"
  "        padding-left: 10px;"
  "        font-size: 9.5px;"
  "}" ;

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), grid);

  GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, css, -1);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display (gdk_display_get_default (),
                                              GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                              GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
  g_object_unref(provider);

  GtkWidget *text = gtk_text_new();
  gtk_grid_attach ((GtkGrid *)grid, text, 0, 0, 1, 1);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


If you remove "all: unset" it works?

I tested the program and it works for me.
The error message appears:
"gtk_accessible_text_get_contents: assertion 'end >= start' failed,"
But this has nothing to do with CSS or the frame.
It seems to be an unresolved problem of gnome.
Maybe also a problem, from X11.
See for example here:
GNOME/gtk/-/issuses/5708
GNOME/gtk/-/issues/6734
